# what jenkins can do other than build?

Tags: jenkins

I have some processes or I can call them as events and after completion of that processes or events I wanted to kick start the backup processes. Is it possible with jenkins? if yes then how to do it? if not what is other the solution.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend the [Jenkins Multi-Job Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin)

This plugin allows you to define conditional steps which only run when the previous step was successful. I use this plugin heavily and highly recommend it to anyone looking to use Jenkins to automate a multi-step process.

Comment: Yes but it requires plugins that extend its functionality. I mainly use it to run shell scripts I have written that do all sorts of things (i.e.: set up my environment, run tests, perform static analysis, etc)

Answer (score 0):

You have two options :

1. Write a post build action to get the backup. For this you can use shell script to where how and what kind of backup you want.
2. Create another job which is responsible for backup. you can trigger that job after successful completion of all your events.

Answer (score 0):

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/thinBackup

You can use this thin backup plugin also.